# MongoDB $group operation - memory usage optimisation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I need to perform a `$group` operation over my entire collection. This group stage is reaching the limit of 100MB RAM usage.

> The $group stage has a limit of 100 megabytes of RAM. By default, if the stage exceeds this limit, $group will produce an error. However, to allow for the handling of large datasets, set the allowDiskUse option to true to enable $group operations to write to temporary files.

I'm not limited by the RAM but I couldn't find how to increase this memory usage limit. **Does anyone know how to config this restriction?**

Setting up `allowDiskUse` to true will solve the solution but I assume the whole operation will be much slower and I'd like to find a better solution.

---

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            producer: "$producer",
            dataset:"$dataset",
            featureOfInterest:"$_id.featureOfInterest",
            observedProperty:"$_id.observedProperty"
        },
        documentId: {$push:"$documentId"}
    }
}
```

This `$group` operation is performed over entire complexe objects (producer and dataset). I understand that this  operation is expensive since "It requires to scan the entire result set before yielding, and MongoDB will have to at least store a pointer or an index of each element in the groups." I'd rather `$group` on uniqueId fields for both of these object.

**How could I $group object using unique ID and `$project` the whole object afterwards?**
I'd like to obtain the same result as the group operation above using the group operation below at the beginning of my aggregation pipeline :

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            producer: "$producer.producerId",
            dataset:"$dataset.datasetId",
            featureOfInterest:"$_id.featureOfInterest",
            observedProperty:"$_id.observedProperty"
        },
        documentId: {$push:"$documentId"}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**allowDiskUse**

There is no option in MongoDB to increase memory usage more than 100mb in aggregations so in heavy pipeline so you have to set the flag to **true**.

***However***

You may be interested reading about **MongoDB In-Memory Storage Engine**

Example starting mongodb with in-memory storage engine in the command line

```
mongod --storageEngine inMemory --dbpath <path> --inMemorySizeGB <newSize>
```

More information in Mongodb docs

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/inmemory/

Regarding the second question - I didn't get it. Please post example documents.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. In memory Sorage engine doesn't seem to suit my use case. Regarding to the second question; `producer` and `dataset` are object identified by IDs. I was wondering if I could `group` using those IDs and retrieve entire `producer` and `dataset` out of the pipeline using `$addFields` in an aggregation operation.